# How to calculate maximum bounding box based on fixed aspect ratio requirement?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am building some UI for users to upload photos and crop them, based on a fixed aspect ratio which is a requirement of my product. This fixed aspect ratio happens to be portrait.

I need to select the largest internal bounding box within user-provided photos based on this aspect ratio. Here are two examples (portrait and landscape):

[image]

[image]

So, given dynamic user-added dimensions, how can I calculate the largest possible crop selection based on my fixed aspect ratio?

```
const FIXED_ASPECT_RATIO = 3 / 4

const usersImageWidth = 800
const usersImageHeight = 550

const cropWidth = ?
const cropHeight = ?
const cropX = ?
const cropY = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i got your question right, but from what I understood, I would try it like this:

```
// Check if picture is portrait or landscape oriented
if (userImageWidth >= userImageHeight) {
// If picture is landscape oriented, max crop height = height
  cropHeight = userImageHeight;
// Width is calculated according to ratio:
  cropWidth = (cropHeight / 4) * 3;
// If picture is portrait oriented, max crop width = width
} else {
  cropWidth = userImageWidth;
// Height is calculated according to ratio:
  cropHeight = (cropWidth / 3) * 4
}
```